# How to push object from Firebase query into this.state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've pulled data from Firebase. Data is there, as console.log confirms this.

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
0:
id: 1.417253735436239
name: {Jack: true}
__proto__: Object
1:
id: 1.7540006580031215
name: {Jack: true, Jill: true}
__proto__: Object
length: 2
```

However, I need to iterate through this data to list the names, but when I try to setState this data into an array (definately declared in the constructor), I get 'Cannot set property 'setState' of undefined.

Here is the code with the setList function that doesn't work:

```
let users = [];
      listRef.on("value", function (snapshot) {
        users.push({
          id: 1 + Math.random(),
          name: snapshot.val()
        })
        console.log(users);
      });
      function setList(users){
        this.setState({ names: users})
      }
      setList();
    });
  }
```

Names is declared as an array in this.state in the constructor.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `setState` is not an object it is an asynchronus function you need to setState like this `this.setState({ name: users})`

Comment: Thannks, Uday. I've updated the question here, but the problem is not resolved - still showing 'Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined'.

Comment: can you update you're question with react component as i'm unable to understand

Comment: I am dealing with similar problem, please check my code in https://github.com/progamandoconro/ReactNativeApps/blob/master/Firebase/WebAdmin/src/pages/HomePage.js

Answer (score 1):

I got past the error. Using a function inside the block was wrong. I moved setState out of the curly brackets and without the function.

```
 setName = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
    let textBox = document.getElementById('inputDivId');
    textBox.style.display = "flex";
    let messagesBox = document.getElementById('messagesDivId');
    messagesBox.style.display = "flex";
    let thinkDel = document.getElementById('options');
    thinkDel.style.display = "flex";
    let nameBox = document.getElementById('nameDivId');
    nameBox.style.display = "none";

    // Add ourselves to presence list when online.
    let name = this.state.name;
    // let names = this.state.names;
    let connectedRef = firebase.database().ref('.info/connected');

    // let users = [];
    connectedRef.on('value', function (snap) {
      if (snap.val() === true) {
        const con = listRef.child(name);
        con.onDisconnect().remove();
        con.set(true);
      }

      let users = [];
      listRef.on("value", function (snapshot) {
        users.push({
          id: 1 + Math.random(),
          name: snapshot.val()
        })
        setList(users);
      });

      function setList(users) {
        this.setState({
          names: users
        })
      }
    });
  }
```

But I am still not getting the data in the this.state.names as needed !

Answer (score 0):

Data is loaded from Firebase asynchronously. While the data is loaded, the main code continues running. Then when the data is available your callback is called.

It's easiest to see this by placing a few log statements:

```
console.log("Before attaching listener");
listRef.on("value", function (snapshot) {
  console.log("Got data");
});
console.log("After attaching listener");
```

When you run this code it logs:

> Before attaching listener
>
> After attaching listener
>
> Got data

This is probably not what you expected, but it is actually the defined behavior. And it also explains why your code doesn't work: by the time you call `this.setState({ names: users })` your callback hasn't run yet, and `users` is empty.

For this reason, any code that requires data from the database must be *inside* the callback, or be called from there. In the case of ReactJS it is quite simple: you just call `setState` from within the callback:

```
let users = [];
listRef.on("value", function(snapshot) {
    users.push({
        id: 1 + Math.random(),
        name: snapshot.val()
    })
    setList(users);
});

function setList(users) {
    this.setState({
        names: users
    })
}
```

---

I'm not completely sure what the data structure at `listRef` looks like, but have a suspicion that you're actually looking for this:

```
listRef.on("value", function(snapshot) {
  let users = [];
  snapshot.forEach(function(user) {
    users.push({
        id: snapshot.key,
        name: snapshot.val()
    })
  });
  setList(users);
});
```

Comment: Hi Frank, thank you for your explanation. I certainly need to work at using Firebase with React. However, the problem persists, even using the code you have written here. In fact, theTypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined is back.  I have since edited the original question to show the entire setName() function to perhaps give a clearer picture. I hope this helps the solution come to light.